# Pandas change index name of items in the list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
          2019   2018
Sally    -6461  -6340
Brian     7139   7200
rebecca   1337   1067
mark     10922  11128
toto     12936  13054
```

and list given as:

```
listVal = ["Sally","rebecca"]
```

for the row that is in `listVal`, I would like to change the name by adding `00`
So that final df looks like this:

```
           2019   2018
Sally00   -6461  -6340
Brian      7139   7200
rebecca00  1337   1067
mark      10922  11128
toto      12936  13054
```

Is there one line code that achieves this without using for loop like below?

```
for val in listVal:
   df.index = df.index.str.replace(val, val+'00')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` with `isin`

```
df.index = df.index.where(~df.index.isin(listVal), df.index+'00')
df
            2019   2018
Sally00    -6461  -6340
Brian       7139   7200
rebecca00   1337   1067
mark       10922  11128
toto       12936  13054
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Sally, Brian, etc. is index names, then pandas have builtin function for renaming column and row names

```
df_new = df.rename(index={'Sally': 'Sally00','rebecca':'rebecca00'})
```

You can use any list to dict methods to programatically create the new names for the rows.

As  @maow suggest you can use the following.

```
df.rename(index={val: val+'00' for val in ['Sally', 'rebecca']})
```

Comment: You can even use `listVal` with dictionary comprehension: `df.rename({val: val+'00' for val in ['Sally', 'rebecca']})`

Comment: Yes it was what i mean by programatically creating. I will edit the answer.